# How to access numpy that was installed with conda

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

Following instructions from [numpy.org](https://numpy.org/install/) I have installed numpy

```sh
conda install numpy
```

The installation was successful, as when I type the above command again, I see the message

```sh
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

However, when I start python with `python` and type `import numpy` I see an error message

```
Python 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How can I get access to numpy?

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and my conda 4.9.2 is installed in
~/.local/opt/anaconda3/ if this can help.

Thanks!

Comment: you probably calling the wrong python. invoke the conda python

Comment: You can do a quick test by calling ~/.local/opt/anaconda3/bin/python and try import numpy

Comment: That works thanks!